# Display data attribute bootstrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, attributes, bootstrap-modal

I want to display my data-attribute in a modal. The problem is, I can only output them in an input field, but not in a div or span tag. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.todolist-destroy-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var id = button.data('id');
            var title = button.data('title');
            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find('#id').val(id);
            modal.find('#title').val(title);
        });
```

This works:

```
<input type="text" id="title" value="">
```

But i need the title in this span tag:

```
<span id="title"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not suppose to use `val()` on a `<span>`
Instead use `text()`
i.e. `modal.find('#title').text(title);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to do. But if you want it inside the span, can't you just append it?

`$('span#title').append(id);`

Also, don't have two elements with the same id.